# Using SqlCommand to execute a non-query, can you get to text normally posted to "Messages"?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

When using SqlCommand to execute a non-query (such as a database restore), is it possible to programatically get the text that would normally be posted to the "Messages" tab if using the Management Studio? And if so how?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, there's an event hook on the SqlCommand object called SqlInfoMessage, which you can hook into:

```
SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=Northwindintegrated Security=SSPI;");

_con.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(_con_InfoMessage);
```

The event handler will look like this:

```
static void _con_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    string myMsg = e.Message;            
}
```

The "e.Message" is the message printed out to the message window in SQL Server Mgmt Studio.

Marc

Comment: +1: Thsi is awesome.  After using ADO.NET for so many years, this is the first time coming across this...

Comment: :-) Glad you like it ! .NET in general is soooo vast - everyone constantly learns and picks up new tricks :-)