# SqlDataReader only returns first select in SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, text

I'm using a [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) to execute a sql statement on a SqlServer2005 db. ( I also tried [DbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.aspx).)

If I execute this sql in SQL Server Management Studio, I can send the "Results to Text".
I would like to capture this text in my C# code.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663716/using-sqlcommand-to-execute-a-non-query-can-you-get-to-text-normally-posted-to) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547040/ms-sql2005-query-stored-proc-results-to-text-using-sqlcommand-or-such) are related questions, but not the same:

My sql contains, next to print statements, also different select statements:

```
PRINT 'We are here'
SELECT Name FROM Table1
-- do some logic
SELECT Name, Country FROM Table1
PRINT 'We are done'
```

( "*Strange sql*" I hear you say. I know, but this is what our long-living maintenance scripts look like.)

I can use the SqlConnection.InfoMessage to catch the PRINT statements separately.

But SqlDataReader doesn't seem to support the 2 select statements, both with a different FieldCount.

I'm afraid I'm stuck with Process.Start and the sql server command line sqlcmd and reading the output, but I was looking for something more *API'ish*.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SqlDataReader should work. Use the `Read` method to go through the rows of the first select, and `NextResult` to move to the results of the second select. Like so:

```
do {
    while (dataReader.Read()) {
        //... process one row
    }
} while (dataReader.NextResult()) //go to the results of the next SELECT
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to call [.NextResult()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx) on your DataReader in order to get the second set of results.